# No module named grass.script

Tags: python

I am having problems importing grass.script - error says no module name grass.script.

I have read the information on http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python#Python_Scripting_Library

and I have set my environmental variables as follows:

```
GISBASE = C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2
GISRC = C:\Users\rjones\AppData\Roaming\GRASS6\grassrc6
GRASS_SH = C:\OSGeo4W\apps\msys\bin\sh.exe
PYTHONLIB = C:\Python27
PYTHONPATH = C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\etc\python
PATH = C:\Python27\;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\etc;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\etc\python;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\lib;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\msys\bin
pythonexe = C:\Python27\
```

If anyone has any suggestions to sort the problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: In the [MS-Windows](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python#MS-Windows) section of the documentation at the link it says that the `GISRC` variable must point to a `".grassrc6"` file, not `"grassrc6"` like you have. It also says that the file "must exist. Run GRASS one time interactively to create it or see below for how to writing it"

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The file does exist already - I had checked this.   have changed the GISRC variable to ".grassrc6".  It still cannot find the module named grass.script

Comment: Well, next I'd debug your module search path with `import sys` followed by `print sys.path` and make sure that the `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\etc\python` folder is one of the things in it. If it is, then make sure there's a `grass` folder in the `...\python` folder. If there is, then make sure it has an `__init__.py` file in it so Python treats it as the name of a package. It should also contain a file named `scripts.py` which is the name of the submodule you're actually trying to `import`.

Comment: So - I think I have found the problem (which I think differs from the one I started out with).   Today I installed OSGeo4W afresh (I uninstalled the previous one).  A result of this was that the grass-6.4.2 directory was renamed grass-6.4.3RC2.  I changed all the paths within the environment variables to take this into account.  However...one of the paths printed out by 'print sys.path' is C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python ...when this path does not exist. Hwever, I am not sure how to alter this path since all the paths in environment settings use grass-6.4.3RC2

Comment: If you found the problem, it would be nice if you answered your own question, as it might be useful to others.

Comment: No, Sorry I don't think I found the answer to the problem.  By re-installing OSGeo4W I changed the problem inadvertently.  I now have the PYTHONPATH set to C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\etc\python somehow (as it's not set like this in environment variables).  I have done a bad fix on this problem by typing in sys.path.append('C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\python') which adds the path I want

Comment: Can't you just change the `PATH` environment variable so it has what you now want in it (C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\python)?

Comment: To do it the "bad" way properly, you would need to have used `sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3RC2\etc\python')` and if you didn't then that's not what fixed things.

Comment: well when I code: sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/grass-6.4.3RC2/etc/python') ...it works, and when I comment it out...it doesn't work.   which suggests that it is fixing it?? and in PATH environmental variable is: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass6.4.3RC2\etc\python which is what I am confused about